# How to measure area from current location to another location using GPS coordinates in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android Tablet,i got a new requirement that i need to find out the distance between one point to other selected point can any one please help me how to achieve this

I found that in google maps we have one option called Measure in Labs menu i need same kind of requirement can any one tell me how to invoke/implement programatically measured feature in Google maps.

Please check the below image for better understanding.

Waiting for your valuable inputs...[image]

I am using below code for showing current gps location now i need to know how to point other location and draw line and then measure area please check my code and suggest me

```
public class Tracking extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

   LocationManager locman;
   LocationListener loclis;
   Location Location;
   private MapView map;

   List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
   private MapController controller;
   String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
   double lat;
   double lon;


   @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         initMapView();
         initMyLocation();
         locman = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         //locman.requestLocationUpdates(provider,60000, 100,loclis);
         //Location = locman.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

      }
   /** Find and initialize the map view. */
      private void initMapView() {
         map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
         controller = map.getController();
         map.setSatellite(false);
         map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      }

      /** Find Current Position on Map. */
      private void initMyLocation() {
         final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
         overlay.enableMyLocation();
         overlay.enableCompass(); // does not work in emulator
         overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               // Zoom in to current location
               controller.setZoom(24);
               controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
            }
         });
         map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
      }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      if (Location != null){
         lat = Location.getLatitude();
          lon = Location.getLongitude();
          GeoPoint New_geopoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1e6),(int)(lon*1e6));
          controller.animateTo(New_geopoint);
          geoPointsArray.add(New_geopoint);


      }

   }
   public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
        double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
        double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                        (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
        double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
        double dist = ang *6371;
        return dist;
    }

   class MyOverlay extends Overlay{
       public MyOverlay(){
       }   
       public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
       super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        Path p = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < geoPointsArray.size(); i++) {
        if (i == geoPointsArray.size() - 1) {
            break;
        }
        Point from = new Point();
        Point to = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i), from);
        projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i + 1), to);
        p.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
        p.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
        }
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 4,5,50, mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        super.draw(canvas, map, shadow);
    }   
}

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Comment: do you know GPS coordinates of both points ?

Comment: @Kousalik i dont know gps coordinates of both points i need current location point

Answer (score 1):

this links might help you

[Using gps get the distance a person has walked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664587/using-gps-get-the-distance-a-person-has-walked)

[GPS - Getting the distance,time while running and walking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662320/gps-getting-the-distance-time-while-running-and-walking)

please go through the links. its explained in detail

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw path between two location then you can refer the below links

[J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

Also from [here](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/#svn/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx) you can get source code.